# Regular expressions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex

What is the correct syntax when dealing with regular expressions in Objective-C?

Suppose I have the following string:

```
NSString *string = @"my string";
```

and the following regular expression:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(a|b)*"];
```

If I had to match the string against this regex, would be following be enough?

```
if(NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(a|b)*"]) {
  // do something
}
```

I am used to Java where the `matches` method already returns `true` if the string matches a regexp ^^

Comment: have you ever tried to read the **[official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW48)**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing in that if-statement is only checking that the regex was created. You never *matched* is against anything.

You are missing the `numberOfMatchesInString:options:error:` method (or any of the other matching methods). They can all be found in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The code you are looking for would be something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"my string";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
    [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(a|b)*" 
                                              options:0 
                                                error:&error];
// Check error here... (maybe the regex pattern was malformed)

NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string 
                                                    options:0 
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])]; // Check full string

if (numberOfMatches > 0) {
    // You have at least one match ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick example of how to use regex

```
NSString *expression = @"^[a-zA-Z_//s]{0,30}$";
    NSString *newString = @"abc";
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];

     if (numberOfMatches == 0)
     {
         NSLog(@"Not Allowed");
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Allowed");
     }
```